# Basic chat application Creating using Socket.io and Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I just tried to create basic chat application using the following instructionhttp://socket.io/get-started/chat/.

When i tried to run  `npm install --save socket.io`

I am getting the following error. How can solve the following error:

```
npm WARN package.json socket-chat-example@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json socket-chat-example@0.0.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json socket-chat-example@0.0.1 No license field.

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-55-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
 cwd /root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-55-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-55-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-55-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
socket.io@1.3.7 node_modules/socket.io
├── has-binary-data@0.1.3 (isarray@0.0.1)
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── socket.io-parser@2.2.4 (isarray@0.0.1, debug@0.7.4, component-emitter@1.1.2, benchmark@1.0.0, json3@3.2.6)
├── socket.io-adapter@0.3.1 (object-keys@1.0.1, debug@1.0.2, socket.io-parser@2.2.2)
├── engine.io@1.5.4 (base64id@0.1.0, debug@1.0.3, engine.io-parser@1.2.2, ws@0.8.0)
└── socket.io-client@1.3.7 (to-array@0.1.3, indexof@0.0.1, component-bind@1.0.0, debug@0.7.4, backo2@1.0.2, object-component@0.0.3, component-emitter@1.1.2, has-binary@0.1.6, parseuri@0.0.2, engine.io-client@1.5.4)
```

Please check this error and what is causing issue?

Please suggest

Comment: what os are you using? and how did you install the node.js?

Comment: @Kichu try with `sudo npm install socket.io --save`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried installing node-gyp and g++?

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

and g++

```
apt-get install g++
```